# Web service output - Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to Azure ML Studio. I tried creating an experiment that takes a numeric value as input and a gives a data table type output. I works fine when I run it in the portal , but not when I run it as a web service. It shows a single value numeric output , when it has to be a data table type.

Is there a way to change the output type of web service output?

[Visualizing output in portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq5Xb.png)

[Test RRS output(web service)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUmN7.png)

Comment: No R content visible. Removed tag, since it will probably attract viewers who will downvote for lack of code or data. (The Azure focussed viewers may be more tolerant.)

Comment: @42- ok ,thank you :)

Comment: Make is a classic web service and see the JSON output getting from it. If it's providing all data you need.. go for it

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne It shows , thanks :)

Comment: @Sundari added as an answer. Better to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne Done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is a classic web service and see the JSON output getting from it. If it's providing all data you need.. go for it.